# Sorting dates already CHAR

Tags: oracle, linq, plsql

I have dates stored in a table like this:

```
9/29/2016 6:00:00 PM
8/31/16 5:48 PM
9/28/16 5:58 PM
9/14/16 5:57 PM
9/1/16 5:57 PM
9/21/16 5:52 PM
9/22/16 5:59 PM
9/15/16 5:59 PM
9/7/16 5:56 PM
9/8/16 5:55 PM
```

I need to sort this column and it is sorting them in alpha order but should be 
sorted like this:

```
8/31/16 5:48 PM
9/1/16 5:57 PM
9/7/16 5:56 PM
9/8/16 5:55 PM
9/14/16 5:57 PM
9/15/16 5:59 PM
9/21/16 5:52 PM
9/22/16 5:59 PM
9/28/16 5:58 PM
9/29/2016 6:00:00 PM
```

How can I get these to sort correctly using PLSQL?
If you know how to do it in Linq, that would be a bonus.

Comment: What is the data type of the column in the table?  Is it actually a `date`?  Or is the column a `char`/ `varchar2`?

Comment: Convert them into dates before sorting. That may be slow, but what else are you going to do?

Comment: @JustinCave, VARCHAR2

Comment: I always wonder how people could store date values as string...

Comment: That is how they come over from GoToWebinar so we just do that vs. converting them before storing. Each to his own...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are the only two date formats, you might be able use something like this:

```
select textdate
     , to_date(textdate,
         case
             when regexp_like(textdate,'^([0-9]{1,2}/){2}[0-9]{2} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M$')
                  then 'MM/DD/YY HH:MI PM'
             when regexp_like(textdate,'^([0-9]{1,2}/){2}[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M$')
                  then 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'
         end) as dt
from   ( select '9/29/2016 6:00:00 PM' as textdate from dual union all
         select '8/31/16 5:48 PM' from dual union all
         select '9/28/16 5:58 PM' from dual union all
         select '9/14/16 5:57 PM' from dual union all
         select '9/1/16 5:57 PM' from dual union all
         select '9/21/16 5:52 PM' from dual union all
         select '9/22/16 5:59 PM' from dual union all
         select '9/15/16 5:59 PM' from dual union all
         select '9/7/16 5:56 PM' from dual union all
         select '9/8/16 5:55 PM' from dual )
order by dt;
```

(Or just order by the case expression - the rest of it included for demo purposes.)

It might actually be simpler to just use plain `%` and `_` wildcards in the case expression - I just tried `regexp_like` first, and gives a bit more control.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a common occurrence, and you may have other date formats in a string column besides the two formats you showed in your test inputs, you may consider building a helper table with two string columns: one withe "match patterns" - to be used in regular expressions - for the different date format models in your "dates-in-string-colum" table, and the other column with the corresponding date format models that would be used in a call to the `to_date()` function.

I illustrate this in the solution below; instead of stored tables, both the "input table" and the "helper table" are shown as factored subqueries. The solution uses a join to identify which date format model should be used for each string.

Then you can use the date in `DATE` datatype, for example, for sorting, as William has shown in his Answer.

```
with
     inputs ( str ) as (                                  -- this is your base table
       select '9/29/2016 6:00:00 PM' from dual union all
       select '8/31/16 5:48 PM'      from dual union all
       select '9/28/16 5:58 PM'      from dual union all
       select '9/14/16 5:57 PM'      from dual union all
       select '9/1/16 5:57 PM'       from dual union all
       select '9/21/16 5:52 PM'      from dual union all
       select '9/22/16 5:59 PM'      from dual union all
       select '9/15/16 5:59 PM'      from dual union all
       select '9/7/16 5:56 PM'       from dual union all
       select '9/8/16 5:55 PM'       from dual
     ),
     format_masks ( re_fmt, dt_fmt ) as (                 -- this is the helper table
       select '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M',
                                    'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi::ss AM' from dual union all
       select '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M',
                                    'mm/dd/yy hh:mi AM'       from dual
     )
-- then the solution (actual SQL query) begins below - yes, just three lines of code!
--
select   i.str, to_date(i.str, f.dt_fmt) as dt
from     inputs i inner join format_masks f on regexp_like(i.str, f.re_fmt)
order by dt
;
```

**Output**: (note - the second column uses my session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter to display dates in `DATE` datatype)

```
STR                   DT
--------------------  -------------------
8/31/16 5:48 PM       2016-08-31 17:48:00
9/1/16 5:57 PM        2016-09-01 17:57:00
9/7/16 5:56 PM        2016-09-07 17:56:00
9/8/16 5:55 PM        2016-09-08 17:55:00
9/14/16 5:57 PM       2016-09-14 17:57:00
9/15/16 5:59 PM       2016-09-15 17:59:00
9/21/16 5:52 PM       2016-09-21 17:52:00
9/22/16 5:59 PM       2016-09-22 17:59:00
9/28/16 5:58 PM       2016-09-28 17:58:00
9/29/2016 6:00:00 PM  2016-09-29 18:00:00

10 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the `TO_DATE` function, with that you can convert data to a date format. Then you can use an `ORDER BY` to order the dates. 
 
[Link for more information on TO_DATE()](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)